# Determine If Solution Compiles using MSBuild and PSake

Tags: powershell, msbuild, powershell-2.0, psake

I have put together a PSake (v2.0) build script, and the script is setting the `$psake.build_success` property as `true` even thought the call to MSBuild fails.   Can  anyone advise me on how to alter the script so that the `$psake.build_success` property will correctly return `false` when the MSBuild call fails?

My PSake build script is as follows:

```
properties {
    $solutionFile = 'SOLUTION_FILE'
    $buildSuccessfulMessage = 'Solution Successfully Built!'
    $buildFailureMessage = 'Solution Failed to Build!'
    $cleanMessage = 'Executed Clean!'
}

task default -depends BuildSolution 

task BuildSolution
{
    msbuild $solutionFile /t:Clean,Build
    if ($psake.build_success) 
    {
        $buildSuccessfulMessage
    } 
    else 
    {
        $buildFailureMessage
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently psake has a bug whereby hanging `{` will only echo the contents and not EXECUTE them.  So, change to `task BuildSolution {` and you should have better results.

Comment: Brett, Thanks for the info, much appreciated.  If you were to leave it as an answer below, I would accept it as the official answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is PowerShell's native `$lastExitCode` (i.e., WIn32 ExitCode) any use in the context? I'd be guessing that the built in one is only relevant when you're invoking a psake-related cmdlet.

i.e., replace the check with

```
if($lastexitcode -eq 0) {
```

Disclaimer: Only podcast level experience with psake :D

Comment: Thanks Ruben, because the actual call to MSBuild is actually successful, but the build operation it initiates fails, this wouldn't work.  +1 for a useful code snippet I 'll be using in the future.

Comment: I'm pretty sure msbuild should set `lastExitCode` - how many levels deep are you trying to go? Normally any msbuild execution failures should just bubble up (i.e. any child builds that fail return a non-zero exit code and that triggers the parrent failings and so on. This discusses the concept:- http://code.google.com/p/psake/issues/detail?id=9

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be that the call to MSBuild operation actually completes successfully, whilst the build operation it initiates fails.  The way I was able to get around this was to pipe the output of the MSBuild call to a text file, and then parse the file for the string "Build Failed".  If it contained the string, obviously the build failed.

My PSake build script is as follows:

```
properties {
    $solutionFile = 'SOLUTION_FILE'
    $buildSuccessfulMessage = 'Solution Successfully Built!'
    $buildFailureMessage = 'Solution Failed to Build!'
    $cleanMessage = 'Executed Clean!'
}

task default -depends Build 

task Build -depends Clean {
    msbuild $solutionFile /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release >"MSBuildOutput.txt"
}

task Clean {
    msbuild $solutionFile /t:Clean 
}
```

and in my calling script:

```
function Check-BuildSuccess()
{
    return (! (Find-StringInTextFile  -filePath .\MSBuildOutput.txt -searchTerm "Build Failed"))
}

function Is-StringInTextFile
(
    [string]$filePath = $(Throw "File Path Required!"),
    [string]$searchTerm = $(Throw "Search Term Required!")
)
{
    $fileContent = Get-Content $filePath    
    return ($fileContent -match $searchTerm)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the psake [Exec](http://jameskovacs.com/2010/02/25/the-exec-problem/) command that you can wrap msbuild with and a powershell error is thrown.

```
Exec {
     msbuild $solutionFile "/p:Configuration=$buildConfiguration;Platform=$buildPlatform;OutDir=$tempOutputDirectory"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither $LastExitCode or $_ worked for me.  This did however:

```
$buildArgs = "MySolution.sln", "/t:Build", "/p:Configuration=Debug"
$procExitCode = 0
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "msbuild" -ArgumentList $buildArgs -NoNewWindow -PassThru
Wait-Process -InputObject $process
$procExitCode = $process.ExitCode

#aha! msbuild sets the process exit code but powershell doesn't notice
if ($procExitCode -ne 0)
{
    throw "msbuild failed with exit code $procExitCode."
}
```

P.S. If you use this in production I recommend adding -timeout handling to Wait-Process